# connection string path dynamically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I made a desktop application in vb.net. I give the reference path of connection string through the .udl. The problem is when I place the folder in another location the path string does not change and hence results in an error. Kindly suggest. Connection details are as follows

```
_connStr = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\avt\Desktop\New folder\a.udl")
con = New OleDbConnection(_connStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you using Text file to save your connection String ?

Go to Project Properties -> Settings and create a ConnectionString setting to save your connection string. That'll solve your problem. Using a Text file for ConnectionString is not a valid way.

Comment: Thanks for yor reply. Its only for knowing that how to access the conncetion string using with text file.please suggest conncetion details using datadirectory

Comment: Well, the Parameter passed in `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` is in a string format. And that will not automatically change even if you change the file location. Put file location in Project Settings(AGAIN), retrieve the setting in string variable and pass the variable to `System.IO.File.ReadAllText()` function. **Path passed in Text format can not be changed dynamically without using variables.**

Comment: can we use |datadirectory| keyword to find the location?               
eg: _
connStr = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("|datadirectory|\a.udl")

Comment: Nope. That will be treated as plain text

Comment: Actually anything that passed in `" "` is treated as plain text

Comment: then how to finf the location

Comment: I think you are still unclear in your question. What do you exactly want to do ? Connect to a db using path in **STRICTLY Text File** ? Kindly be clear.

And answer to your above question is already posted above